# How to change height of slider in Materialize css?

Tags: materialize

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="img/s1.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And Here is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slider();
});
```

Slider works perfectly but the height is 400px by default. How can I change it to 300px?

EDIT:

Changing image size doesn't change the height of slider (height is always 400px)

I tried this: `<div class="slider" style="height:300px;">` , it also doesn't work.

Comment: try giving `max-height:300px`

Comment: Also, if you replicate it somehow via snippet, then it will be helpful for us to understand..

Comment: Giving `max-height:300px` doesn't work

Comment: I found a solution, `$('.slider').slider({height:300});` solved my issue. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

In JQuery we can set the height and other options (https://materializecss.com/media.html) like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.slider').slider({ 
        full_width: true,
        height : 800, // default - height : 400
        interval: 8000 // default - interval: 6000
    });

});
```

We don't need to change image dimensions for that.

Answer (score 2):

https://materializecss.com/media.html#slider

In OPTION section in the materialize docs - you can add/edit defoult values.
in jquery I don't know how it work but in pure javaScript is easy.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
var instances = M.Slider.init(elems, options);
});
```

The option parameter get object with properties - that you can find on the docs in the link.
For example:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
var instances = M.Slider.init(elems, {'height' : 770, 'indicators' : true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this issue is already solved i just want to share another option.
By default slider height is 400px so if we want to change default value we need to use **!important** tag like bellow.

```
<style>
   .slider{
      height: 300px!important;
   }
</style>

    <div class="slider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <img src="img/s1.jpg">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add !important

`<div class="slider" style="height:300px !important;">`